# Neo4j similar paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i want to do a query that will take all users (without a pre-condition like user ids) , and to find the common similar path**s**. (for example top 10 users flows)

For example:

User u1 has events: a,b,c,d

User u2 has events: b,d,e

Each event is a node with property event-type

the result should look like:

```
[a,b,e] - 100 users

[a,c,f] -80 users

[b,d,t]- 50 users

.......
```

the data the generated the 1st aggregated row in the result can be for example:

user 1: **a,b**,c,**e**

user 2: **a,b,e**,f

.........

user 100: **a**,c,t,**b**,g,**e**

i wonder if this link can help:
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-with-equal-weights-on-relationships

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: fine, but if you store your data in elastichserach (as far as i know), the word "thanks" will be saved once(as far as i know) , so whats the reason for that?

Comment: What's the reason you didn't read the link I included?

Comment: thanks John i'll defiantly read it. are you the group admin btw?

Comment: Dude, please learn where you are. Read the topics in the [help].  This site is community-moderated. That's especially true of community members with reputation numbers 10,000 and up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Cypher query that returns all the `Event` nodes that user 1 and user 2 have in common (in a single row):

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: 1}) -[:HAS]-> (e:Event) <-[:HAS]- (u2:User {id: 2})
RETURN u1, u2, COLLECT(e);
```

[Added by MichaelHunger; modified by cybersam] For your additional question try:

```
// Specify the user ids of interest. This would normally be a query parameter.
WITH [1,2,3] as ids
MATCH (u1:User) -[:HAS]-> (e:Event)
// Only match events for users with one of the specified ids.
WHERE u1.id IN ids
// Count # of distinct user ids per event, and count # of input ids
WITH e, size(collect(distinct u1.id)) as n_users, size(ids) AS n_ids
// Only match when the 2 counts are the same
WHERE n_users = n_ids
RETURN e;
```

Comment: Very nice! Is there similar syntax for x users? Such as " most common events for all users"

Comment: @MichaelHunger: Thanks for the additional query. I have optimized it a bit.

Comment: hi @cybersam, i have edited my question to clarify the results structure, since i'm not sure how to use your solution as a generic one for my data

Comment: any chance you look again at the question?